# Can't pass pointers to scanf("%s",ptr);

Tags: c, string, pointers, scanf

So I commented out the scanf part (and just initialized it with my own string), why does it crash if I use scanf? I believe the actual arguments I've put in scanf(); are correct.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int strendmilan(char *s,char *t)
{
    int scntr = 0,tcntr = 0;
    while(*(s+(scntr++)) != '\0')
        ;
    --scntr;
    while(*(t+(tcntr++)) != '\0')
        ;
    --tcntr;
    while(tcntr >= 0)
        if(*(s+scntr--) == *(t+tcntr--))
            ;
        else
            return 0;
    return 1;
}
int main()
{
    char *s,*t; 
    /*
    scanf("%s",s);
    scanf("%s",t);
    */
    s = "HAHAHACOOL";
    t = "COOL";
    if(strendmilan(s,t) == 0)
        printf("NOT");
    else
        printf("YES");
    getch();
}
```

Comment: Assign some memory to `s` before calling `scanf`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that you are sending `scanf()` a pointer to a buffer (e.g., `s`) where it can store the information read, *but* you haven't allocated any buffer space pointed to by `s` (and same for `t`)

```
char *s,*t; 
scanf("%s",s);
```

So you can either allocate an array of char for `s`, or use `malloc()` to allocate some storage and assign the return value of that call to `s`.

Comment: But s = "HAHAHACOOL";
 t = "COOL"; works even if i dont allocate space

Comment: @vincentbelkin that really doesn't change anything I posted. `scanf` wants a pointer to a location where it can store data. You create the pointer, and then immediately call `scanf` *without* having allocated any storage for `s` to point to (and for `scanf` to successfully use).

Comment: @vincentbelkin, `t="COOL"` implicitly allocates some memory to store the string literal, then assigns the location of that memory to the pointer variable.  `scanf` expects the pointer variable to already point to allocated memory, into which it will place the characters read.

Comment: I think i'm misunderstanding something, but doesn't s = "HAHA"; require me to use malloc(); to allocate storage space too? why does it work?

Comment: @vincentbelkin It's a string literal (think of it as a constant if that helps). Also see DaveCosta's comment. Also, even if this worked, you are doing this *after* your call to scanf ...